English Translation from the german word "IT Systemhaus"
I am new to this site. I hope I am on the right one, as it looks like it has more than just one for English.
What I am looking for is the correct translation of the German term "IT-Systemhaus."
The word-for-word translation would sound like "IT Systemhouse," but I don't think that is correct.
As a result of my research, I have discovered a multitude of diverse options:

IT service provider
IT solutions provider
Managed service provider (MSP)
IT consulting firm
IT services company
IT support company
IT infrastructure provider
IT outsourcing company
IT management company
Technology services company
Network solutions provider
Systems integrator
IT engineering company
Information technology provider
Computer services company
Tech support services
Enterprise solutions provider
Business technology services provider

To me as a non-native, it seems like some of them are similar, but I suspect they are not.
Who can enlighten me here?
Update:
The usual usage of the German "IT Systemhaus" is that some customers don't have an internal IT department and buy the resources on demand for support, projects, or even hardware and software. In fact, some have internally administrators but want to use it for the expertise.
Update 2, Translation with DeepL:

An IT system house (not the correct spelling: IT system house or simply system house) is traditionally a supplier of hardware and software. It acts as a bridge between the manufacturers and the end customer, so to speak, and handles the procurement and installation of hardware and software in the end customer's company. It is also often the point of contact for the functionality of the supplied and implemented IT infrastructure components during operation.
However, most IT system houses have long since outgrown this original definition. With increasing digitalization, they have developed into IT service providers with extensive and growing product portfolios. IT system houses are therefore now professional IT service providers that offer their corporate customers many other IT services in addition to IT procurement, including IT consulting, IT support and IT management.
IT system houses employ professional IT experts, each of whom is usually assigned a specialty. Depending on what a corporate customer needs, the IT system house can provide the right IT specialist to ensure optimal customer support. This provides an initial answer to the question of what an IT system house is. However, you may have further questions about system houses.
What does an IT system house do?
The general answer to this question is: An IT system house (not the correct spelling: IT system house) offers business customers services in the field of IT. However, it is not possible to specify which services these are in detail, as the service portfolio and areas of specialization are different for every IT service provider.
In principle, IT system houses have two main tasks: On the one hand, they offer their corporate customers rapid support in the event of IT emergencies and, on the other, they try to ensure that IT emergencies, IT failures and IT problems do not occur in the first place by implementing a wide range of preventive measures. Find out more:
Immediate help or break/fix
Suppose a network or server failure occurs in a company. As soon as the IT service provider is notified, they analyze the problem. This can either be done remotely or require an on-site appointment. Once the source of the fault has been identified, the problem is rectified immediately to avoid long - and costly for the company - downtimes. In this case, the IT system house is paid according to the time required.
Prevention or managed services
With comprehensive IT services, IT system houses do everything they can to prevent IT emergencies from occurring in the first place. This often begins with an analysis of a company's IT infrastructure and the creation and implementation of an IT strategy on this basis. This includes measures such as the optimization of the IT infrastructure, the introduction of comprehensive security mechanisms and the implementation of monitoring software. In this way, the IT system house keeps a permanent eye on the entire company IT or even sub-areas. It can react to the slightest signs of anomalies and initiate measures before a malfunction occurs. The technical term for this type of permanent IT support is managed services. These are usually charged on a subscription model.
The break/fix model used to be commonplace, but the managed services model is now becoming increasingly popular with system houses. This is practical for corporate customers: they hand over responsibility for part or all of their IT.
The help desk employee of an IT system house telephones a customer and provides remote support. But what is an IT system house? Image: Pexels/Olha Ruskykh
Acute problems? IT system houses can often provide remote support. Image: Pexels/Olha Ruskykh
What IT services do IT system houses offer?
IT system houses offer a very broad portfolio of IT services. However, this portfolio looks different for every IT service provider, depending on how they set their priorities. As a rule, most system houses offer IT services in the areas of IT support, IT security, IT infrastructure and cloud solutions. Many individual IT services then fall into these four main areas. Here is a brief overview:
IT infrastructure:
The IT services provided by IT system houses start by setting up, analyzing and optimizing the IT infrastructure of companies. To this end, the system houses procure and implement new hardware and software and set up PC workstations, telephone systems, (virtual) servers and video surveillance systems.
IT support:
As part of IT support, IT service providers also take over the management of IT infrastructure components during ongoing operations, help with the digitalization of business processes during the transition to a paperless office or introduce commercial software.
IT security:
IT security is becoming increasingly important as the threat of cyber attacks on companies grows. IT system houses put the IT infrastructure to the test with an IT security check and penetration test. And with anti-virus management, firewall management, patch management and backup management, they keep a constant eye on IT security.
Cloud solutions:
The future lies in the cloud - and IT system houses are helping companies to get there. They relocate classic infrastructure elements such as servers, firewalls and workstations to the cloud and implement data backup and email archiving in the cloud.
You can find an overview of the most important IT services on our website. But remember: not every IT system house (represented in our network) offers each of the IT services - this is where the aforementioned focal points of the various system houses come into play.


Can you provide a description of what exactly this term means, for those of us not fluent in German? As you've discovered, there are a lot of terms in English, and to give advice on which one you need it's helpful to know the details about what the German term means and the context in which you want to use it.

Is it 'IT-Systemhaus' or 'IT Systemhaus'? Is it a company name?

By the way, we don’t speak of “word-to-word” translations, but instead, word-for-word. The former (non idiomatic) construct may be motivated by the thought that each word in the original language is changed to a counterpart in the other language. In that case, you can replace that one with the thought that for each word in the original we substitute a counterpart. In any event, word-to-word translation isn’t used in English.

I have added the requested details to the question. A systemhaus describes the function like an IT technician, but there are usually not only one, and most of them are specialists for a specific product.

Do you mean most Systemhaus companies specialize in a specific product, or most employees of Systemhaus companies specialize in a specific product? This may make a difference for the appropriate English word.

From the edit, are they 'outsourced'?

I see IT Service Supplier built into the opening translation.

Are the solutions running on-premise or off-premise, and are they on single-tenant or multi-tenant servers? Or is your company agnostic in those respects?

A lot of the options you listed are indeed appropriate, and often more or less synonyms - to some extent, it can come down to simply branding (what does a company want to say it does).
Based on your description, the closest ones would likely be:

IT infrastructure provider
IT outsourcing company
IT solutions provider
IT services provider
IT services company
Enterprise solutions provider

So essentially, I think you're looking for "IT X provider", with whichever word the company prefers as X.
If they are targeting a specific market segment, things like "Enterprise", "Network", "Security" etc. also come into play as options instead of "IT".
As you can see I don't think there is a single correct answer, but I hope this helps.
(source: 20+ years of experience in the tech sector)

Thank you for the great answer! I'd like to give others a chance to respond before I make a decision.

"Since no one else wants to propose a different answer, I am going to accept yours."
